# Is there any way to test the condition of a brake booster and master brake cylinder outside of the car?

Tags: brakes, vw, golf

The brake booster and master brake cylinder on my car are leaking so I bought a 2nd hand set from a guy with a doner car. Is there anyway to test them before I install them?

Car is a 92 Mk1 Golf/Rabbit Cabriolet, so no electronics on these - all vacuum and hydraulics.

Comment: if they're already assembled use a vacuum or pressure pump on the booster inlet. if it doesn't hold than you have a leak. you'd have to bench bleed the master off the booster to test for leaks. if you have an adapter for the reservoir you can pressure test the master cylinder with the ports blocked.